# flex- Drag and drop

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I am trying to drag and drop an object across the SkinnableContainer- am coming across a very strange issue

The drop occurs only at a few places- elsewhere it just shows the "X" sign and on dropping there, reverts to original position. I have used very standard commands... from function 2 to function 3, the call occurs very rarely as seen in trace statements- any guidance on why this happens?

I added the following code to SkinnableContainer: `dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event);" dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event);`

**(1)**:

```
private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void    
{
  var dragInitiator:Image = Image(event.currentTarget);   
  var ds:DragSource = new DragSource();    
  ds.addData(dragInitiator,"img"); //made change here    
  DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, ds, event);
}
```

**(2)**:

```
private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void {

if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("img"))
{
   trace("came here"); //comes here for each mouse move     
   DragManager.acceptDragDrop(SkinnableContainer(event.currentTarget));
}
```

**(3)**:

```
private function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {    
trace("in drag drop handler"); //doesn't come here for most places
```

Comment: You're not showing the code as to where the drag is starting.

Comment: What exactly is the question? All I get out of what you posted is you want to know is why 2 functions only get called "very rarely"

Comment: I understand my question was poorly framed- couldn't think of a better way to frame the inconsistent behavior... anyways Merv was right on the money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Using Flex 4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fed.html) reference:

> To use a container as a drop target, you must use the `backgroundColor` property of the container to set a color. Otherwise, the background color of the container is transparent, and the Drag and Drop Manager is unable to detect that the mouse pointer is on a possible drop target.

In the subsequent example, they use an mx container (`Canvas`), but I checked the AS3 reference, and `spark.components.SkinnableContainer` does have a style [`backgroundColor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html#style%3abackgroundColor).

I haven't tried this myself, so please confirm whether it is the issue.  From your description that only certain parts of the container are registering the `dragEnter` event, this seems like a consideration that would lead to such effects.

Comment: Yes- once I add a background color  to skinnable container, the behavior of dropdown is very consistent